# Как сгруппировать по дню и посчитать среднее значение столбца?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

Есть документ Excel, в котором присутствуют 2 столбца, 1 = дата и время, 2 = проценты.
Необходимо чтобы считалось среднее значение столбца N для каждого дня (у каждого дня есть несколько строк со временем когда эти значения N были получены),
т.е. в конце работы нужен просто массив со значениями пример: `N=(70, 20, 60,...)`.

В начале я открываю файл и делаю парс:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.ExcelFile("облака1.xlsx")
df1=df.parse(df.sheet_names[0])
```

Далее, я хотел делать циклы которые будут пробегать по строкам и смотреть если значения даты из 1 столбца совпадают то мы берём первые 2 цифры из 2 столбца и кидаем в массив, а после как только значение даты меняется мы вычисляем среднее, перекидываем это число в конечный массив N, а наш текущий очищаем и делам всё сначала для текущей новой даты.

В правильном ли я иду направлении или всё это можно сделать гораздо проще?

Файл прикреплён: [Файл Excel](https://yadi.sk/i/gcKwXt_t-GV11g)

Comment: Если бы у вас в столбце `N` были числа вместо неоднозначных строк, то все решение состояло бы из одной строки. А так львиная доля решения придется на преобразование столбца `N` к осмысленным числам...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем Excel и парсим дату и время:

```
In [29]: df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\download\облака1.xlsx', parse_dates=[0])

In [30]: df.dtypes
Out[30]:
Местное время в Сухобузимском    datetime64[ns]   #  <--- NOTE!
N                                        object
dtype: object
```

создаем столбец с осмысленным числом из столбца `N`:

```
In [31]: df['num'] = df['N'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)').astype(float).groupby(level=0).mean()
```

получилось:

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]:
    Местное время в Сухобузимском                          N   num
0             2018-08-15 22:00:00                    20–30%.  25.0
1             2018-08-15 19:00:00                       60%.  60.0
2             2018-08-15 16:00:00                  70 – 80%.  75.0
3             2018-08-15 13:00:00                  70 – 80%.  75.0
4             2018-08-15 10:00:00                    20–30%.  25.0
5             2018-08-15 07:00:00                  70 – 80%.  75.0
6             2018-08-15 04:00:00                  70 – 80%.  75.0
..                            ...                        ...   ...
737           2018-05-15 19:00:00  90  или более, но не 100%  95.0
738           2018-05-15 16:00:00                  70 – 80%.  75.0
739           2018-05-15 13:00:00                  70 – 80%.  75.0
740           2018-05-15 10:00:00  90  или более, но не 100%  95.0
741           2018-05-15 07:00:00                  70 – 80%.  75.0
742           2018-05-15 04:00:00                       60%.  60.0
743           2018-05-15 01:00:00                       60%.  60.0

[744 rows x 3 columns]
```

группируем по дню и считаем среднее для `num`:

```
In [34]: res = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Местное время в Сухобузимском', freq='D'))
                  ['num']
                  .mean()
                  .reset_index(name='Avg'))
```

результат:

```
In [35]: res
Out[35]:
   Местное время в Сухобузимском        Avg
0                     2018-05-15  74.375000
1                     2018-05-16  86.875000
2                     2018-05-17  83.750000
3                     2018-05-18  83.125000
4                     2018-05-19  73.333333
5                     2018-05-20  90.625000
6                     2018-05-21  76.875000
..                           ...        ...
86                    2018-08-09  52.857143
87                    2018-08-10  25.000000
88                    2018-08-11  53.333333
89                    2018-08-12  96.875000
90                    2018-08-13  91.250000
91                    2018-08-14  89.375000
92                    2018-08-15  58.571429

[93 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Pandas, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814), что вы уже сделали ;)